# Is there a way to assign Multiple Functions to One Function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible in Javascript so that when 1 function is called, it calls multiple functions assigned to it?

Below is what I want to do:

```
var player1= {name: "Chris", score: 1000, rank: 1};
var player2= {name: "Kristofer", score: 100000, rank: 2};

function playerDetails(){
alert("The name of the player is "+ this.name + "."+ " His score is : "+ this.score + "and his rank : "+ this.rank);
}

function playerDetailsSecond()
{
//Do something else
}

player1.logDetails= playerDetails;
player2.logDetails= playerDetails;

//Is it possible to do this?
player1.logDetails += playerDetailsSecond;
player2.logDetails += playerDetailsSecond;

player1.logDetails(); //calls both playerDetails and playerDetailsSecond
player2.logDetails(); //calls both playerDetails and playerDetailsSecond
```

The += specifically is what I want to do.

I know an option is to do something like:

```
function combined()
{
playerDetails();
playerDetailsSecond();
}

player1.logDetails = combined;
```

But I am hoping to see if the first one is an option to see possible syntaxes / use cases.

Thank you!

Comment: `+=` won't work like that.  What's the problem that you are trying to solve? Are you going to have lots of players that you need to attach multiple functions to? Are the functions going to vary between players?

Comment: I am working with ChakraBridge to expose .NET classes into Javascript. In this case, LogDetails is actually an Event in .NET which I subscribe to using += in .NET. I was hoping that Javascript had something similar but maybe a different syntax.

LogDetails = playerDetails does work (ex. raise event in .NET, Javascript function gets called), but I am wondering what if I want to run multiple functions subscribed to the event?

Comment: Why don't just use callback or promise, which runs `playerDetailsSecond()` after `playerDetails()`?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an event emitter (or in general, an observer pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I've written a more abstracted syntax to implement the same. Look at previous answer for explanation.

```
var player1 = { name: "Chris", score: 1000, rank: 1 };

function playerDetails(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("The name of the player is " + this.name + "." + " His score is : " + this.score + "and his rank : " + this.rank + arg1 + arg2);

    //make sure you add this line at the end
    arguments.callee.invokeExtras(this, arguments);
}


//you do not need to look into this code.
// this code adds functionality of pushing extra functions.
playerDetails.addFunction = function(fn) {
    this.extraFns?this.extraFns.push(fn):this.extraFns = [fn];
}
playerDetails.invokeExtras = function(context, args) {
    this.extraFns?this.extraFns.forEach(function(fn) { fn.apply(context, args) }):null;
}
//upto here

function playerDetailsSecond(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("The name of the player is " + this.name + arg1 + arg2);
}

function playerDetailsThird(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("new extra funtion " + this.name + arg1 + arg2);
}


player1.logDetails = playerDetails;

player1.logDetails.addFunction(playerDetailsSecond);
player1.logDetails.addFunction(playerDetailsThird);

player1.logDetails("test1", "test2");
```

**Previous Answer**

This is how you can implement this.
The concept here is to treat functions as first class objects which means functions can have properties.

Now the first function you are going to have has to have two extra lines at the end.

```
 var self = this;
 arguments.callee.extraFns.forEach(function (extraFunction) { extraFunction.call(self) });
```

and after declaration of the function, you need to add an empty array `extraFns` to the function.

Here is the complete code:

```
var player1 = { name: "Chris", score: 1000, rank: 1 };

function playerDetails() {
    console.log("The name of the player is " + this.name + "." + " His score is : " + this.score + "and his rank : " + this.rank);

    var self = this;
    arguments.callee.extraFns.forEach(function (extraFunction) { extraFunction.call(self) });
}

playerDetails.extraFns = [];

function playerDetailsSecond() {
    console.log("The name of the player is " + this.name);
}

function playerDetailsThird() {
    console.log("new extra funtion " + this.name);
}


player1.logDetails = playerDetails;

player1.logDetails.extraFns.push(playerDetailsSecond);
player1.logDetails.extraFns.push(playerDetailsThird);

player1.logDetails();
```

Let me know if this solves what you want to do or if you do not understand anything here.

Comment: Thanks pranav, it works! Last question, what if I have some parameters on the child function as well?

Comment: welcome!!
All you functions need to have same number of arguments and you can just pass them to extraFunction.call(self,a,b,c..)

Also. you could upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for that.

Comment: @Water look at improved syntax.  I think that's more abstracted

Answer (score 1):

If your just looking for syntactic sugar then I am not aware of anything like that. `Array.push()` is probably the shortest way to append generic Objects to something.

The simplest method is to have a function call multiple functions as you suggest. If you attach the function to a `Player` class then all players will inherit the same function.

```
class Player {

  logDetails () {
    function1(arguments)
    function2(arguments)
  }

}
```

If you are looking to programatically add functions then you could implement something on the `Player` class.

For all players

```
class Player {

  static addLogFn (fn) {
    this.logFunctions.push(fn)
  }

  logDetails () {
    for (let fn of this.constructor.logFunctions) {
      fn.apply(this, arguments)
    }
  }

}
Player.logFunctions = []

let player1 = new Player()
player1.name = 'meee'
player1.rank = 'peon'
Player.addLogFn(function(arg){console.log(this.name, arg)})
player1.logDetails('a') // => "meee a"
Player.addLogFn(function(arg1, arg2){console.log(this.rank, arg2)})
player1.logDetails('b','c') // => "meee b\npeon c"
```

Or use the instance of Player if you want to set the functions for individual players

```
class Player {

  constructor () {
    this._logFunctions = []
  } 

  logDetails () {
    for (let fn of this._logFunctions) {
      fn(arguments)
    }
  }

  addLogFunction (fn) {
    this._logFunctions.push(fn)
  }

}
```

Maybe look at the ES2015 [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object too. It allows you to modify a target objects behaviour, which is in the same ballpark but might not apply well here.